# MongoServerError: Authentication failed. When using mongo+docker+nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

I'm getting an authentication failed when trying to connect to a mongoDb in a docker container.

> failed to connect to mongoDB  MongoServerError: Authentication
> failed.
> at MessageStream.messageHandler (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:462:30)      at
> MessageStream.emit (node:events:394:28)    at processIncomingData
> (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:108:16)
> at MessageStream._write
> (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:28:9)
> at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:389:12)    at _write
> (node:internal/streams/writable:330:10)    at
> MessageStream.Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:334:10)
> at Socket.ondata (node:internal/streams/readable:749:22)    at
> Socket.emit (node:events:394:28)    at addChunk
> (node:internal/streams/readable:312:12) {   ok: 0,   code: 18,
> codeName: 'AuthenticationFailed' }

This is my docker-compose.yaml

```
# docker compose version which is currently 3.8
version: "3.8"

# services : is a list of our container

    services:
      mymongodb:
        image: "mongo"
    
        ports:
          - "27017:27017"
    
        volumes:
          - data:/data/db
    
        environment:
          MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: "mongo"
          MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: "mongo"
        command: [--auth]
      backend:
        build: ./backend
        ports:
          - "8080:8080"
    
        depends_on:
          - mymongodb
    
      frontend:
        build: ./backend
    
        ports:
          - "3000:3000"
        volumes:
          - ./backend/src:/app/src
        stdin_open: true
        tty: true
    
        depends_on:
          - backend
    
    volumes:
      data:
```

And this is my connection using mongoose and nodejs:

ps: tried adding ?authSource=admin to my connection string to no result.

```
mongoose.connect(
      "mongodb://host.docker.internal:27017/user",
      {
        auth: {
          username: "mongo",
          password: "mongo",
        },
        authSource: "admin",
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
      },
      (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error("failed to connect to mongoDB");
          console.error(err);
        } else {
          console.log("mongodb is running and secured");
          app.listen(PORT);
        }
      }
```

I've tried using user@user on the connecttion string to no avail.
Also created the user in the admin database and it connects without a problem

```
# mongo -u mongo -p mongo --authenticationDatabase admin
MongoDB shell version v5.0.6
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?authSource=admin&compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("cdb011a0-4aa1-472c-bc66-fd491db87b62") }
MongoDB server version: 5.0.6
================
```

Adding my dockerfile just in case:

```
FROM node:16.5.0-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["npm","start"]
```

Comment: in the last code block (where you connect to mongo from the terminal) you have the user/password as `mongo` but in the connection code you have it as `user`

Comment: It's a mistake I was testing to see what was wrong with it and tried creating other users and messing around to see if I could fix it, edited the question to the prior code which I'm having trouble with.